# How to change the button text in an Activity when the activity receives broadcast?

Tags: android, broadcast

I have a button in activity, now I want the button text change when a file finished decompress.I have done it like the following, and register the broadcast within the activity. My problem is how the get the activity instance in `onReceive()` method.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiveDecompressionNotification = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the solution by now, this might help you out, since it's about pretty much the same thing:
In my case I wanted to change a button's text, when my `service` has stopped playing a sound. So after playback following will be executed:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent("CHANGE_BUTTONSTATE");
        i.putExtra("state", "play");
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }});
```

Like you I registred my `BroadcastReceiver` within the activity, which is doing the request. The corresponding `onReceive()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String state = intent.getExtras().getString("state");
    playButton.setText(state);
}};
```

Where `playButton` has been declared in the activity's `onCreate()`:

```
Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
```

This approach might not be the best, since I'm a beginner - So any improvements and suggestions are appreciated.